# System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll c# making login to the file. sql

Tags: c#

im creating e grades project on c#, and i cant normally connect to database. Writing https://i.stack.imgur.com/itJuX.png 
Maybe you can help me ? Not working in login.cs. Last job then i do it it was working.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dienynas.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users", conn);
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int id = 0;
            bool pass = false;

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                if (sdr[0].ToString() == textBox1.Text && sdr[0].ToString() == textBox2.Text)
                {
                    pass = true;
                    id = (int)sdr[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (pass == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password for this user is incorrect");
                id = (int)sdr[0];
                pass = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Form1 frm = new Form1(id);
                Hide();
                frm.Show();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code can be broken in a second, simply by opening the database using SSMS. Why ask a *Windows* user for a username/password in the first place? The system already know who he/she is, the connection to the database is already made using Windows Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your if statement after the loop.

```
if (pass == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Password for this user is incorrect");
    id = (int)sdr[0];
    pass = true;
}
```

In that `if` block you are accessing your `SqlDataReader`, which very possibly has exited the `while` loop after returning `false` upon reading indicating that there is no more data to be read.  If there is no data, then you will get an error when attempting to read data that is not there.

I would think that one of the reasons you are exiting the while without ever having a match is that, unless both `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` contain a matching string you will never have a match.  The following line is comparing those text box values to the exact same data value. Unless the text is identical between those text boxes then this statement will always be false.

```
if (sdr[0].ToString() == textBox1.Text && sdr[0].ToString() == textBox2.Text)
```

I am guessing that you intended something like this:

```
if (sdr[0].ToString() == textBox1.Text && sdr[1].ToString() == textBox2.Text)
```

**Edit**
With all of that being said, there is a lot of room for refactoring in this code. For one thing, generally performing database operations in a button handler can lead to unresponsive dialog windows and is something to be avoided.  You are also using some other objects which are disposable and so you should be cleaning those up as well.  I will rewrite the function a little to show you some of the cleanup, but I don't have time to go through splitting it into threads and it is outside the scope of your question.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataReader sdr = null;
    try
    {
        var textBox1 = textBox1.Text;
        var textBox2 = textBox2.Text;

        conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dienynas.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
        conn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users", conn);
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        int id = -1;
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            var text0 = sdr[0].ToString();
            var text1 = sdr[1].ToString();

            // NOTE: You could add the string comparison type here as well
            if (text0.Equals(textBox1) && text1.Equals(textBox2))
            {
                id = (int)sdr[0];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (id == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password for this user is incorrect");
        }
        else
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1(id);
            Hide();
            frm.Show();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sdr?.Dispose();
        cmd?.Dispose();
        conn?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working, i think problem is cant read sql date files.  Whats why i cant make login function

Comment: always writing invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: @mausasu1234 - What line is the exception being thrown on? You posted an image of the message box you are displaying. Post the actual exception along with the stacktrace. Step through with a debugger. I am almost certain you are getting the exception in your if statement after the while loop because "pass" is always false, because I suspect you are reading through all rows of the table, but have no match because of the other if statement and so you exit the while with no more rows to read, but you try to access data from a non-existent row.

Comment: @mausasu1234 what did you try? Apart from this being an extremely weak way to check for passwords, the original code had too many problems. What did you try this time? Did you try debugging? And why are you writing your own code in the first place, one that can be broken in 1 second - the time it takes to open that database with SSMS?